# How to stop an once-visited website from appearing in Safari search bar?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

On my iPhone, this website at the top of the search bar keeps appearing despite my attempts to clear it from the suggestions.

- Clearing history and website data doesn’t help.

I wonder if creating a new Apple ID might help as my current Apple ID had an email address changed in the past. Maybe that’s a clue (a bug somewhere?).

[image]

Are there places to clear this user-generated data on iOS?

Answer (score 1):

Check history, reading list, and bookmarks for this link.

This seems to be a Safari-Siri suggestion. You can turn them off in Settings -> Safari -> Safari Suggestions.

There's also Clear History and Website Data button there.

Comment: They’ve been all clear. The link persists.

Comment: See the updated answer @across_the_wild_8

Comment: Doesn’t work still. Seems to be an old history entry that hasn’t been properly deleted. I don’t see much sense in submitting a bug report as it appears to be an unreplicable issue. That leaves me only with the new Apple ID option. @anki

Answer (score 0):

It will disappear due to lack of use without you doing anything as long as you don’t revisit it. Your device will decide the website is unused. Failing this   ….. Settings > Scroll down to Safari >Scroll down to Clear history and website data. !!! Doing this regularly will free up your phone for quicker data transfer, if that doesn’t work you have stored it as a bookmark or reading list. In Safari, check The bar with little glasses and and open book, press them and you can see and delete unwanted items.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question since the original question states "Clearing history and website data doesn’t help."